# Jackson set time format globally in object mapper

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to set a specific format for any serialized `LocalTime` with jackson.

It works fine with `@JsonFormat`, but this is only valid for specific properties and not for all serialized with `ObjectMapper`. Besides, I use a custom `BeanSerializerModifier` and it doesn't seem to recognize the properties marked with `@JsonFormat`.

I can do it for dates using `ObjectMapper.setDateFormat`, however, there doesn't seem to be a method like it for times. Is there any easy way of doing it?

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463049/date-format-mapping-to-json-jackson :)

Comment: I wish! I need a `HHmm` format and tried with `mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HHmm"));` but this is ignored when serializing `LocalTime` objects

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952472/serialize-deserialize-java-8-java-time-with-jackson-json-mapper

Comment: Seems like most of these answers are suggesting to use the `JavaTime` module, but I'm already using it so it doesn't help. The other solution is using a custom serializator which I've also considered (I'd have to use it in my `BeanSerializerModifier`) but this seems a bit overkill, I mean, it's pretty easy for dates, so why not for times?

Comment: I had a similar problem a few years ago, maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40487656/jackson-java-time-iso-8601-serialize-without-milliseconds

Comment: @BenjaminM really good! This works! Although I'm still wondering if there's something simpler

Comment: @G9QV2 The answers there provide some alternatives, for example using `@JsonFormat`, but that's of course not global. Else I'd say: Just go for it. 5 lines of code you can put in some "config" class and silently ignore